# Qt::nativeEvent doesnt get called

Tags: c++, qt

Why does the `nativeEvent` function never get called?

```
    // .h
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    
    
    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
      
        bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long*);
    
    //private slots:
      //  virtual bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result) override;
    
    private:
        Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
    
    //protected:
      //  bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result);
    };

   
    //.cpp
    bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result)
    {
       //...
    }
```

I found some similar question where people suggest to define it as `override` but when i try:

```
bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long*) override;
```

It doesn't compile with the error: `member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member`.

Commented lines was other ways I tried to define it, but I got the same error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of [**QWidget::nativeEvent()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) is:

```
bool QWidget::nativeEvent(
  const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, qintptr *result)
```

Thereby, [**qintptr**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qintptr-typedef) is an

> Integral type for representing pointers in a signed integer (useful for hashing, etc.).
>
> Typedef for **either qint32 or qint64**. This type is guaranteed to be the **same size as a pointer on all platforms supported by Qt**. On a system with 32-bit pointers, qintptr is a typedef for qint32; on a system with 64-bit pointers, qintptr is a typedef for qint64.

(Emphasize mine.)

According to the reported error,
`member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member`
on OPs platform `sizeof (long) != sizeof (qintptr)`.

E.g. on my platform (Visual Studio 2019 with target `x64`)

- `sizeof (long)`: 4
- `sizeof (qintptr)`: 8.

If the signature of a virtual member function doesn't match the signature of the overridden virtual base class member function the latter is just not overridden. To make such cases detectable by the compiler, the `override` identifier was introduced to make the intention clear.

Hence, without `override` it just doesn't work. (I would've expected a warning of the compiler but that might depend on the compiler settings.) However, with `override` the compiler is forced to emit an error in this case.

The fix is obvious: OP should use `qintptr*` instead of `long*` for the last parameter `result`.

If it's expected to be in fact a `long` in the specific case of OP, it can be explicitly converted in the body of the function.

---

Please, note that `sizeof (long)` is platform dependent as well: [Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) and usually varies between 32 and 64 bit. Thereby, it's always 32 bit in Visual Studio (with `x86` as well as with `x64`) but 64 bit in Linux with g++ and target `x64`. (I forgot how it is when g++ emits 32 bit code on Linux…)